# Layout Issue in HTML form

Tags: html, css, layout, html-table

I am trying to make an html form that has various fields. I have created separate divs and using jquery to animate them. On the main page, when I click **"manage users"** button some elements gets displayed on page. What I am trying to achieve is to align these fields properly using a table  element but when I use `<table>` tag the **form elements gets displayed outside the div.** How can I make it so when I click the **"manage users"** button the elements are properly displayed using table tag.

Here is my code :

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#flip").click(function(){
        $("#panel").slideToggle("fast");
        $( "#panel1" ).hide( "slow");
        $( "#panel3" ).hide( "slow");


    });


    $("#ff").click(function(){
        $("#panel1").slideToggle("fast");
        $( "#panel" ).hide( "slow");
        $( "#panel3" ).hide( "slow");

    });

    $("#man_users").click(function(){
        $("#panel3").slideToggle("fast");
        $( "#panel" ).hide( "slow");
        $( "#panel1" ).hide( "slow");

    });
    });
```

```css
  #ff,#flip,#man_users,#add_user{

    padding: 5px;
    //text-align: center;
    background-color: #D9ECF5;
    border: solid 1px #88949A;



    }
    #panel,#panel1,#panel3 {
    padding: 5px;
    //text-align: center;
    background-color: rgb(0,136,159);
    border: solid 1px #88949A;
    color:white;
}

#panel,#panel1,#panel3 {
    padding: 50px;
    display: none;
}

#ff:hover,#flip:hover ,#man_users:hover,#add_user:hover{ 
    background-color:#A0CFE6;
}
body {
  font: 13px/20px 'Lucida Grande', Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;
  color: #404040;
  background: #0ca3d2;
}
#containier{
    margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;

    background-color:white;
    width:50%;
    font-size:10px;
    text-align:center;

}
h1{

  line-height: 40px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #555;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 1px white;
  background: #f3f3f3;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #cfcfcf;
  border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, whiteffd, #eef2f5);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, whiteffd, #eef2f5);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, whiteffd, #eef2f5);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, whiteffd, #eef2f5);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px whitesmoke;
  box-shadow: 0 1px whitesmoke;

}
#dd,#panel3{
    text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="containier">
    <h1>admin panel</h1>
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td><input type="button" id ="ff" value="generate report"><br></td>

            <div id="panel1">
            <form id="f1" action="viewer.php" method="post">
            <select id="pickerhtml"  name="select">
            <option>2015</option>  
            <option>2016</option>
            <option>2017</option>
            <option>2018</option>
            <option>2019</option>
            <option>2020</option>
            </select>
            <input type="text" id="name">
         <input type="submit" id="ffj" value="view report"><br>

        </form>
        </div>


    <td><input type="button" id="flip" value="Manage Links"><br></td>
     <div id="panel">
        <form action="block_conf_controller.php" method="post" >
        <div id ="dd">
        <input type="checkbox" name="jan" value="Bike">January<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="feb" value="Car">Feburar<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="mar" value="Bike">March<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="apr" value="Car">April<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="may" value="Bike">May<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="jun" value="Car">June<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="jul" value="Bike">July<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="aug" value="Car">August<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="sep" value="Bike">September<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="oct" value="Car">October<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="nov" value="Bike">November<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="dec" value="Car">December<br>
            <input type="submit"  value="save" ></form>
        </div>
      </div>
      <td><input type="button" id ="man_users" value="Manage Users"><br></td>
      </tr>
      <div id="panel3">

      <form>
      <select id="add"  name="select1">
            <option>Employee</option>  
            <option>Admin</option>
            </select>
            User Name: <input type="text" name="user_name" id="user_name" placeholder="First name">
            Password:  <input type="password" name="password" id="pass" placeholder="**************">

      <input type="button" id ="add_user" value="Add User"><br>

      </form>

      </div>
      </table>
      </div>
```

Comment: can you share the code while using table tag.

Comment: @danish443 the code shared has already the table tag...

Comment: i am trying to add a table tag inside panel3 div

Comment: so that its elements get properly aligned

Answer (score 1):

You complete HTML structure is incorrect.
You have `div` outside `TD`, you have `form` closed after the its container...
I tried to clean it up but not sure about the result...

You'd better try to validate your dom using w3c validator

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#flip").click(function(){
        $("#panel").slideToggle("fast");
        $( "#panel1" ).hide( "slow");
        $( "#panel3" ).hide( "slow");


    });


    $("#ff").click(function(){
        $("#panel1").slideToggle("fast");
        $( "#panel" ).hide( "slow");
        $( "#panel3" ).hide( "slow");

    });

    $("#man_users").click(function(){
        $("#panel3").slideToggle("fast");
        $( "#panel" ).hide( "slow");
        $( "#panel1" ).hide( "slow");

    });
    });
```

```css
#ff,#flip,#man_users,#add_user{

    padding: 5px;
    //text-align: center;
    background-color: #D9ECF5;
    border: solid 1px #88949A;



    }
    #panel,#panel1,#panel3 {
    padding: 5px;
    //text-align: center;
    background-color: rgb(0,136,159);
    border: solid 1px #88949A;
    color:white;
}

#panel,#panel1,#panel3 {
    padding: 50px;
    display: none;
}

#ff:hover,#flip:hover ,#man_users:hover,#add_user:hover{ 
    background-color:#A0CFE6;
}
body {
  font: 13px/20px 'Lucida Grande', Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;
  color: #404040;
  background: #0ca3d2;
}
#containier{
    margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;

    background-color:white;
    width:50%;
    font-size:10px;
    text-align:center;

}
h1{

  line-height: 40px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #555;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 1px white;
  background: #f3f3f3;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #cfcfcf;
  border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, whiteffd, #eef2f5);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, whiteffd, #eef2f5);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, whiteffd, #eef2f5);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, whiteffd, #eef2f5);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px whitesmoke;
  box-shadow: 0 1px whitesmoke;

}
#dd,#panel3{
    text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="containier">
    <h1>admin panel</h1>
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td>
        <input type="button" id ="ff" value="generate report"><br>

            <div id="panel1">
            <form id="f1" action="viewer.php" method="post">
            <select id="pickerhtml"  name="select">
            <option>2015</option>  
            <option>2016</option>
            <option>2017</option>
            <option>2018</option>
            <option>2019</option>
            <option>2020</option>
            </select>
            <input type="text" id="name">
         <input type="submit" id="ffj" value="view report"><br>

        </form>
        </div>

    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="button" id="flip" value="Manage Links"><br>
      <div id="panel">
        <form action="block_conf_controller.php" method="post" >
        <div id ="dd">
        <input type="checkbox" name="jan" value="Bike">January<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="feb" value="Car">Feburar<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="mar" value="Bike">March<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="apr" value="Car">April<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="may" value="Bike">May<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="jun" value="Car">June<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="jul" value="Bike">July<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="aug" value="Car">August<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="sep" value="Bike">September<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="oct" value="Car">October<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="nov" value="Bike">November<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="dec" value="Car">December<br>
            <input type="submit"  value="save" >
        </div>
        </form>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
         <input type="button" id ="man_users" value="Manage Users"><br>
      
          <div id="panel3">

         <form>
          <select id="add"  name="select1">
            <option>Employee</option>  
            <option>Admin</option>
            </select>
            User Name: <input type="text" name="user_name" id="user_name" placeholder="First name">
            Password:  <input type="password" name="password" id="pass" placeholder="**************">

         <input type="button" id ="add_user" value="Add User"><br>

         </form>

         </div>
      </td>
      </tr>
      </table>
      </div>
```

Comment: this produces completly wierd results

Comment: Yes but html is correct... It is exactly what you wrote. I just fixed the dom structure

Comment: You went to a lot of effort. OP @Ashishkumar read up on HTML and review ben's code again.